# What means HRI above lotus and moon?

Tags: reference-request, mahayana, meditation-practicalities

What does mean the syllable HRI above lotus and moon? 
What does mean those visualised aspect separately and together?
What kind of inner feelings they should evoke?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably referring to this:

[image]

It is a "seed syllable" used for meditative visualisation, notably in the Tibetan Chenrezig prayer/ritual. The incantation phrase of this ritual reads:

**Hri** Le P’hag Chog Chen re zig